# How to populate UICollectionView with array of data?

Tags: swift, aws-amplify

I have a UICollectionView that I populate with data from an AWS Amplify List Query function. The array of data from the function successfully prints out to the console but it only returns 1 cell with elements from one `authuserPost` and the corresponding the fields. I have set the struct `UserPostData` to equal the elements inside of the `posts` array. My problem is that my for loop only gets data for one post and only showing one cell when there should be 5 total cells. However when I `print(element)` it shows all 5 post with their own elements. Can anyone point me into the right direction as to what I am doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import Amplify
import AmplifyPlugins
import AWSMobileClient

struct UserPostData {
    var id: String?
    var userSub: String?
    var zipcode: String?
    var contactMethod: String?
    
}

class UserPostsViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var userSubID = String()
    var numberOfPosts = Int(0)
    var data = [UserPostData]()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        fetchData()
        setupUI()
    }
    
    lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: collectionViewLayout())
        collectionView.register(CollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell")
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .tertiarySystemBackground
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return collectionView
    }()
    
    func fetchData(){
        userSubID = AWSMobileClient.default().userSub!
        let post = authuserPost.keys
        let predicate = post.userSub == userSubID
        _ = Amplify.API.query(request: .list(authuserPost.self, where: predicate)) { event in
            switch event {
            case .success(let result):
                switch result {
                case .success(let posts):
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.numberOfPosts = posts.count
                        self.collectionView.reloadData()
                        
                        for element in posts{
                            self.data = [UserPostData.init(id: element.id, userSub: element.userSub, zipcode: element.zipcode, contactMethod: element.contactMethod)]
                            print(element) //When I print element it shows all post and their elements. The Output will be at the bottom of the question.
                            
                        }
                        
                        //print("Successfully retrieved list of posts: \(posts)")
                    }
                case .failure(let error):
                    print("Got failed result with \(error.errorDescription)")
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Got failed event with error \(error)")
            }
        }
        
    }
    
}

// MARK: - UICollectionViewDelegate & Data Source
extension UserPostsViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count // It only returns one cell
        
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        cell.dogImageView.image = UIImage(named: "image1")
        cell.zipcodeLabel.text = data[indexPath.section].zipcode
        cell.contactMethod.text = data[indexPath.section].contactMethod
        cell.layoutSubviews()
        return cell
    }
    
}
```

When I `print(element)` inside of the for loop i get this to the console.

```
authuserPost(id: "0600D60E-2270-4B1A-AE8C-7E42F2B32F9C", userSub: "47bcd9ba-78f9-4d2f-9685-8a97b3a69e77", zipcode: "30316", contactMethod: "(444)085-5666")
authuserPost(id: "6FDD8A2D-D6A6-4CDC-AD05-5D5E085178DD", userSub: "47bcd9ba-78f9-4d2f-9685-8a97b3a69e77",  zipcode: "30308", contactMethod: "(444)869-6665")
authuserPost(id: "58A3431C-7AAE-4AB0-B89E-87D932C09017", userSub: "47bcd9ba-78f9-4d2f-9685-8a97b3a69e77", zipcode: "30316", contactMethod: "(444)869-4534")
authuserPost(id: "C9DF31BE-6FC0-410C-90EE-24E13617199F", userSub: "47bcd9ba-78f9-4d2f-9685-8a97b3a69e77", zipcode: "30316", contactMethod: "(444)869-4534")
authuserPost(id: "5BD76C91-7D3A-424B-99F7-6330EE0AD6AF", userSub: "47bcd9ba-78f9-4d2f-9685-8a97b3a69e77", zipcode: "30316", contactMethod: "(444)869-3453")
```

Comment: Have you set up the collectionview's delegate method "cellForItem(at:)"? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618088-cellforitem. That is where you would dynamically set up the cells

Comment: @GabrielPires Sorry I forgot to mention I have that and i added it into the edited question. My problem is getting the elements out of the array.

Comment: Oh no worries. How does your declaration for the "posts" array look like?
You need to assign it in the `case .success` switch case:

Set it like this: `self.posts = posts` before the reloadData() call

Comment: @GabrielPires I dont have `posts` declared anywhere else but this function. `posts` is from the AWS backend DynamoDB table.

Comment: Oh, I see, that's interesting. What kind of properties does UserPost have? You should create a var at the top of your class `var userPosts: UserPost`. Then in your `case .success(let posts):`... you should assign `self.userPosts = posts`. Then You can utilize userPosts in the `cellForItemAt:` method below. Does that make sense?

Comment: The properties for posts are  `id` , `usersub`, `filename`, `zipcode`, and `contactMethod` . When I declared `var userPost: UserPost` i got an error saying **Use of undeclared type 'UserPost'** @GabrielPires

Comment: you need to declare that variable though. Perhaps you are missing an import. Find out which framework the UserPost is in and import that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216456/discussion-between-gbmr-and-gabriel-pires).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you loop through the posts array and assign [UserPostData.init(...)] to it, you are actually reassigning the self.data property over and over again. Only the last one will survive.

So instead of assigning to the array, you should append UserPostData for each post in the iteration.

---

You should replace

```
self.data = [UserPostData.init(id: element.id, userSub: element.userSub, zipcode: element.zipcode, contactMethod: element.contactMethod)]
```

with

```
self.data.append(UserPostData.init(id: element.id, userSub: element.userSub, zipcode: element.zipcode, contactMethod: element.contactMethod))
```